# How to switch root view of inertia in laravel?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs

I have a website where I want to setup multiple layouts.

**auth layout :** for (login, register etc) pages

**dashboard layout:** for authenticated users to show dashboard and all other pages related to it there.

I have tried to change root view in controller but it didn't work

```
Inertia::setRootView('dashboard');
```

dashboard.blade.php : it contains sidebar for logged in users and have different style theme

```
<!doctype html>
...
<div class="rt-wrapper">
     @include('partials.sidebar')
     <main id="rt-main" class="rt-main rt-haslayout">
        <div class="rt-dashboard">
             @inertia
        </div>
     </main>
</div>
...
</html>
```

auth.blade.php : it only contains login, register etc pages and no sidebar with different style theme.

```
<!doctype html>
...
<div class="rt-wrapper rt-wrappernopadding">
    <div class="rt-loginpagewrapper">
        @inertia
    </div>
</div>
...
</html>
```